# Passing multiple parameters to PHP through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

I am trying to update a table using variables that I created on my JavaScript. I am trying to use ajax to send the information. For some reason whenever I run the code the table is updated with blank and not with the VARIABLES that I created on JavaScript.
Any ideas of what could be causing it?

PHP:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE seats SET firstClass=? , economicClass=? WHERE 1");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $first, $eco);
$eco = $_POST["eco"];
$first = $_POST["first"];
```

JAVASCRIPT/AJAX:

```
var seatsInEconomicClass = 0;
var seatsInFirstClass = 0;
function ajaxWay() {
        $.post("reservePhp.php", 
        { 
            data : {eco:"seatsInEconomicClass",first:"seatsInFirstClass"}
        }, display);
    }
```

Comment: Initialized `$eco` and `$first` with `$_POST` variables before binding. You are first binding and then assigning.

Comment: You are using the variables before initializing it. As @Thamilan pointed out, initialize `$eco` and `$first` before using them.

Comment: Thanks ! I fixed that but I still dont get the values to my database.

Comment: Can you echo $_POST the whole variable itself as see. I think here you will have to use $_POST["data"] ["eco"]  to get those values in a PHP variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close:

```
var seatsInEconomicClass = 0;
var seatsInFirstClass = 0;
function ajaxWay() {
        $.post("reservePhp.php", { eco: seatsInEconomicClass, first: seatsInFirstClass}).done(function(data){
            //code to run after the ajax call
        });
    }
```

From **[jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)**

```
 $.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

here "John" and "2pm" are actual values. whereas in your code you're using variables. if you put them in `quotes` they'll be treated as strings themselves and their value won't reach to php. what'll reach is the name of those variables as strings.

Comment: Should I just remove the quotes ?

Comment: They are variables, right? if yes, then you should remove the quotes.

Comment: Also you'll need to reorder your variable assignments in your php like a lot of people answered here. i only took care of your ajax concern. your php is still wrong.

Comment: I fixed the php but I didnt fix it. my php is like this now                       $.post("reservePhp.php", 
       { 
      data : {eco:seatsInEconomicClass, first:seatsInFirstClass}
        }, function (data) {
     console.log(data);
     });

Comment: I just updated the javascript for you, check again with the updated code.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it ! Do you mind explaining why I need the .done ?

Comment: yes. it's from `promise` api. meaning after completing the ajax request, a `promise` is returned with a method(done) in it, which can take a callback function as an argument. (function(){..}). and that function is executed when ajax completes. **[take a look at this](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jquery AJAX as follows and pass multiple parameters as follows:

```
$.post('reservePhp.php',{param1:value,param2:value,...},function(data){
  //data contains the response on which you can perform any type of action on the html page
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP Code change order of these lines.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE seats SET firstClass=? , economicClass=? WHERE 1");

$eco = $_POST["eco"];
$first = $_POST["first"];
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $first, $eco);
```

First you need to initialize and then Bind them as mentioned in comment by @Thamilan

Comment: That didnt fix it. It is weird that when I console.log(data) echoing the variables I got nothing in return

Answer (score 0):

```
you have need to add a get or  post method for this ajax call
```

you can use this

```
var seatsInEconomicClass = 0;
var seatsInFirstClass = 0;
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"reservePhp.php",
            data:{"seatsInEconomicClass": seatsInEconomicClass,"seatsInFirstClass": seatsInFirstClass},
            success: function(response){ 
            alert(response);
            }
        });
```

you can accees these variables on reservePhp.php with

```
<?php
$seatsInEconomicClass = $_POST['seatsInEconomicClass'];
$seatsInFirstClass = $_POST['seatsInFirstClass'];

?>
```